# C++ Program not Outputting as expected using .get

Tags: c++, file, get, output

My prototype program isn't outputting as expected. I want to store 'Y' within the string **active**, but it's storing NA instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    char testChar;
    string active;
    inFile.open("test.dat");

    inFile.get(testChar);
    if (testChar = 'N')
    {
        inFile.get(testChar);
        if (testChar = 'A')
            active = "NA";
        else
            active = "N";
    }
    else
        active = "Y";
    cout << endl << active << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My textfile(text.dat) is just

```
Y
```

My expected output is **Y**

Actual Output **NA**

Not sure why this is happening

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand the difference between assignment (`=`) and testing for equality (`==`).

Change:

```
if (testChar = 'a')
```

To

```
if (testChar == 'a')
```

And similarly for the other cases.

Note that if you had compiled with warnings enabled the compiler would have reported these simple mistakes.